# Multivariable functions that are not continuous

Tags: functions

Say we have a 2-variable function $f(x,y)$ which is not defined at $(x,y) = (0,0)$ (so perhaps a fraction of some sort).

Say I wanted to make this a continuous function in $(0,0)$ by defining it to be of a certain value at this point. If the function was a single variable, I'd set it's value at $x=0$ equal to the limit of the function as x approaches 0.

What is the equivalent method for above when it comes to 2 variables? Is it simply the limit as x,y approach 0,0? How would one calculate this limit, and if it didn't exist, would it be impossible to make f(x,y) continuous on (0,0)?

An example of $f(x,y)$: $\frac{sin(x)}{x^2+y^2} $

Comment: Even with single variable, it's not like taking a limit solves your problems. The limits from different sides may not match. The same is true with multiple variables.

Comment: Okay, so I could set y = 0, then calculate the limit as x -> 0, and keep doing something of this sort, and if I find a "side" that doesn't give me the same limit as the others, it doesn't exist? And then we can't make f continuous?

Comment: That's correct. The limit may depend on the direction from which you approach $(0, 0)$ and the function can be continuous only if the limits from all directions match.

Answer (score 1):

If you have continuous function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ and there exists $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y) = L$, then the function

$$g(x,y) = \begin{cases} f(x,y) \mbox{ if } (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\ L \mbox{ if } (x,y)=(0,0) \end{cases} $$

Then $g$ would be continous and the restriction of $g$ to $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\}$ is precisely $f$